# How can I see the CPU usage of one process over multiple cores?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, cpu, cpu-usage

I know that on Linux I can measure 300% CPU load for a process which means it burns 3 cores for 100%.

I wonder if I can have this information on Windows. I only can see overall CPU load in `perfmon->Process->% CPU`, but it doesn't provide this information about multiple cores.

How can I have this 300% on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Resource Monitor (C:\WINDOWS\System32\resmon.exe) might be more what you're looking for.  While I have not seen Windows report values over 100% it does record processor time multiplied by cores used.  This can be seen in the Details tab of task manager (C:\WINDOWS\System32\taskmgr.exe /7).  Task manager also will give you an overall cpu usage view or a logical processor view by core (right click the graph to access).